# Can I use the output clause in the Update command to generate 2 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I can use OUTPUT to generate the before and after row values when doing an update to a table.  And I can put these values into a table.

But they go into the table in 1 single row.

I need the before values as a row, and the after values as a new row.

So this snippet isn't working for me at the moment, but it shows the thing I am trying to do.  Is there any way to do this using OUTPUT.

```
update dbo.table1
set employee = employee + '_updated'
OUTPUT 'd',DELETED.* INTO dbo.table2,
OUTPUT 'i',INSERTED.* INTO dbo.table2,
WHERE id = 4 OR id = 2;
```

This snippet below works, but only creates a single row:

```
update dbo.table1
set employee = employee + '_updated'
OUTPUT 'd', DELETED.*, 'i', INSERTED.* INTO dbo.table2,
WHERE id = 4 OR id = 2;
```

I can do it using triggers, but that's not allowed in this case.

And I can do it manually (selecting what I'm going to update into table2, then doing the update...)

Any tips or hints appreciated on how to do it just using just OUTPUT in the update?

Rgds, Dave

Comment: I don't believe SQL Server supports multiple output clauses in such statements.

Comment: You can output into a table-variable and then do a select/UNION to convert into separate rows, as a separate step, if this really is a sane thing to do (almost always, it is more sensible to have all of the data on a single row, otherwise you often need to effectively rebuild such a thing but have to manually re-correlate the inserted and deleted rows)

Comment: @GordonLinoff is absolutely correct. It doesn't make sense to have more than 1 output.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on an answer given in the comments:

```
declare @TempTable table (
    d_id int, 
    d_employee varchar(50),
    d_other varchar(50),
    u_id int,
    u_employee varchar(50),
    u_other varchar(50)
)

update Table1
set employee = employee + '_updated'
output deleted.id d_id, deleted.employee d_employee, deleted.other d_other, 
    inserted.id u_id, inserted.employee u_employee, inserted.other u_other
    into @TempTable
where id = 4 or id = 2;

insert Table2 (change_type, employee_id, employee, other)
select
    'd',
    d_id,
    d_employee,
    d_other
from @TempTable

union all

select
    'i',
    u_id,
    u_employee,
    u_other
from @TempTable
```

I made some assumptions about your schema as it wasn't given, but this should get you started.

Comment: If you substitute `UNION ALL` where you've written the second `INSERT` up to the end of its column list, that is indeed what I was suggesting.